# Joining a 3 tables by using some condition in mysql?

Tags: mysql, sql, join

I have a task to get the count of one column from 3rd table from 1st table (main table) with Condition.
Here I have 3 tables

```
 **tr_t_assessments**
AssessmentID 
Assessmentname  
QuestionSetID

**tr_t_questionsetdetails**
QuestionsetID
QuestionID

**tr_t_questions**
QuestionID
Questioname
Difficultylevel
```

Note: QuestionsetID means there are no of questions in Questionset(for ex:Emcet questionset)

Questionid:each Question in QuestionSet have one ID called "QuestionID"

difficultyLevel:Each Question having Difficulty levels like "Low", "High", "Medium"

**Now i want count(DifficultyLevel) where DifficultyLevel="Low" for each QuestionSet**

my Effort is:

```
 select 
  A.AssessmentID,
  A.AssessName,
  A.ValidFrom,
  A.ValidTo,
  (select count(QuestionID) from tr_t_questionsetdetails where QuestionSetID=A.QuestionSetID) as NoOfQuestions,
  COUNT(C.DifficultyLevel) as Lowlevel,
  from tr_t_assessments A
  inner join tr_t_questionsetdetails B on B.QuestionSetID=A.QuestionSetID 
  inner join tr_m_questions C on **C.QuestionID= (??????)** and C.DifficultyLevel='L'
```

Here above Query points `C.QuestionID = A.QuestionID` (Which is not present in main table)

How do I get that. I want count (difflevel) for each Questionset..

Comment: hi Frazz...i am dng in mysql.If any one knows mysql, sure he knows sql too..that's way i was tagged to both :-)

Comment: @sureshchowdary05 don't be so sure about that ;)

Comment: @sureshchowdary05 `sql-server` is Microsoft product

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use a conditional aggregate to get your count:

```
 SELECT a.AssessmentID,
        a.AssessName,
        a.ValidFrom,
        a.ValidTo,
        COUNT(q.QuestionID) AS NoOfQuestions,
        COUNT(CASE WHEN q.DifficultyLevel='Low' THEN 1 END) AS LowLevel,
        COUNT(CASE WHEN q.DifficultyLevel='Medium' THEN 1 END) AS MediumLevel,
        COUNT(CASE WHEN q.DifficultyLevel='High' THEN 1 END) AS HighLevel
FROM    tr_t_assessments AS a
        INNER JOIN tr_t_questionsetdetails AS qsd 
            ON qsd.QuestionSetID = a.QuestionSetID 
        INNER JOIN tr_m_questions AS q
            ON q.QuestionID = qsd.QuestionID
GROUP BY a.AssessmentId, a.AssessName, a.ValidFrom, a.ValidTo;
```

So in this line:

```
COUNT(CASE WHEN q.DifficultyLevel='Low' THEN 1 END)
```

The count function is only counting low difficult questions (for other questions the case statement returns NULL which is not counted in the COUNT function).

Answer (score 0):

Join C.QuestionID to B.QuestionID

```
inner join tr_t_questionsetdetails B on B.QuestionSetID=A.QuestionSetID 
inner join tr_m_questions C on C.QuestionID = B.QuestionID and C.DifficultyLevel='L'
```

C joins B, B joins A. All is fine.
By the way. You may want to use left join on A to B joining to get 0-count results.